# Change the WordPress files structure

Tags: directory

for a client I need redesign a Website that contains a lot of files in a folders structure that is like this www.website/assets/files/Subfolders

as you can see i wrote "Subfolders" because they are more than one.

Now the website is built using another CMS and I need to work on WordPress.

I would like to know if is possible to create a similar structure where client can easy upload files via Dashboard.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Gravity Form saves the files that are submitted by its form in its own folder. IIRC, path is wp-content/uploads/gravityform/upload something like this. However, GF uses its own UI, not default Media Library.

Comment: In short, if you use custom structure, WP doesn't recognize it which means you can't use the benefit of WP. And you have to deal with your own setting page like Gravity Form.